# Checking for duplicate test cases

Tags: ruby, validation, overriding

In Ruby, I am given a task to run a method. The method carries out if the inputted string has only been inputted once, It will throw an exception for duplicates. So
for the method valid, these are the expected results:

```
valid("John") #=> John
valid("Jack") #=> Jack
valid("John") #=> throw an exception
```

Would anyone know how to write valid so once called it will determine if a specific input has already been ran?

By request this is what I have so far

```
names = []
  def valid(name)
  names.include? name ? rescue TypeError "Duplicate input" : names << name
  end
```

Comment: Where the `valid` method is defined? Inside which class/module?

Comment: Inside the test case I'm guessing. I can't see anything except the valid method

Comment: How about calling `uniq!` on the `names` array to remove the dupes?

Comment: What array? There isn't an array, that's the problem I'm having. There's just an empty method and it wants me to somehow save data inputs to memory to read and make sure they weren't used previously. By calling a method you only access the method, so the array outside valid doesn't work, and initializing an array or hash inside the method will wipe it every time the method calls with another test case.

My problem is I don't know how to track which data inputs have been used already from the unit testing given the only part you write is the callee method that takes only one object as an arg.

Comment: I uniq! might work if I could store into a data structure somehow